# Universal covering Spaces Drawings

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I just have trouble drawing universal covers, how can I draw the universal covers of the following spaces:

1. $X$ is the union of a circle with a projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ identified along a point
2. $X$ is the union of a circle with a 3-Ball identified along a point
3. $X$ is the union of a torus and a circle identified along a point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each space, you can first "unwrap" the circle, obtaining a line (the universal cover of the circle) with countably many copies of $\mathbf{P}^2$ (or the $3$-ball, or a torus) attached at regular intervals. Then "unwrap" each of the attached spaces, obtaining (respectively) $2$-spheres, $3$-balls, or planes attached along the line at regular intervals. (All three universal covers embed "nicely" in $\mathbf{R}^3$.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Some of the books, including Munkres and J. M. Lee, are a little bit abstract in that sense.